# Laravel 5.2 with PWA

Tags: php, laravel, progressive-web-apps

I am using laravel version 5.2 and I am trying to make it a PWA. For long hours of searching google and stackoverflow I can't find any suitable guides that will help me to make my laravel 5.2 app a PWA.. Can anyone help me? Please Ive been trying for a weeks already. I also tried creating my own service worker and manifest but the dynamic URL is the problem it doesn't render anything it just return to 127.0.0.1/dashboard . I am still on my localhost so PWA is supported by it.

Comment: Did you try to follow [this article](https://justmegareth.com/2017-07-15-progressive-web-app-in-laravel/)? It looks decent.

Comment: Another good resource to look for is [this post from github](https://github.com/hafidzi/laravel-pwa). Also to help you implement your service worker, you may want to check [this example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-pwa). Lastly, you can dig deep in the [PWA documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can is on the route, you need create a specific route to your manifest.json and to your worker.js. This is an example to manifest.json:

```
Route::get('/manifest.json', 'YourController@Action')->name('manifest');
```

In controller action you need response a json.

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'name',
    'short_name' => 'short name',
    'start_url' => '/',
    'display' => 'standalone',
    'theme_color' => '#000000',
    'background_color' => '#000000'
]);
```

How reference you can see this repository https://github.com/silviolleite/laravel-pwa